# BPF: mark in structure __skbuff is not writeable?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, network-programming, iptables, ebpf

I have a BPF code (section "`classifier`"). I use this to load to an interface using the tc (traffic controller) utility. My code changes the mark in `__skbuff`. Later when I try to catch this mark using iptables, I observe that the mark I edited has disappeared.

Code:

```c
__section("classifier")
int function(struct __sk_buff *skb)
{
    skb->mark = 0x123;
```

I use the iptable mangle table's below rule to see if the mark is written correctly.

```
# iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i <my_interface> \
    -m mark --mark 0x123 \
    -j LOG --log-prefix "MY_PRINTS" --log-level 7
```

Following are the TC commands I used to load my bpf programs ;

```
# tc qdisc add dev <myInterface> root handle 1: prio
# tc filter add dev <myInterface> parent 1: bpf obj bpf.o flowid 1:1 direct-action
```

Comment: `skb->mark` is definitely [writable](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/core/filter.c?h=v5.2#n6644) for TC classifiers. Not sure why you can't see your marked packets though. I'm no iptables expert, but how is the `--log-level 7` option supposed to work? Could it be setting a log level for the packets lower than what your kernel actually displays in its logs? Unless you're certain, I'd try with `--log-level warning` or something like that just to double check.

Comment: I tried with --log-level warning also. No luck.

Comment: Hmm. Is your classifier working as expected otherwise? E.g. if you make it drop all packets, does it comply?

Comment: @Qeole, Yes. It does.

Comment: I don't remember how the `PREROUTING` table hooks in regard to TC classifiers. Did you try capturing on `INPUT` to see if there's a difference?

Comment: Scratch that. `PREROUTING` is after ingress qdisc, that's not where your issue is. But it's a good thing you added your tc commands: You seem to be attaching your filter on the egress side!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your `tc` commands. You are attaching your filter on the egress side.

The `root` parent refers to the egress side, used for traffic shaping. If instead you want to attach your filter on the ingress side, you should use something like this (no handle needed):

```
# tc qdisc add dev <myInterface> ingress
# tc filter add dev <myInterface> ingress bpf obj bpf.o direct-action
```

Or, better practice, use the BPF-specific qdisc `clsact`, which can be used to attach filters for both ingress and egress (not much documentation on it, besides its [commit log](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=1f211a1b929c804100e138c5d3d656992cfd5622) and [Cilium's BPF documentation](http://docs.cilium.io/en/latest/bpf/) (search for `clsact`)):

```
# tc qdisc add dev <myInterface> clsact
# tc filter add dev <myInterface> ingress bpf obj bpf.o direct-action
```

Comment: ,. Thanks. I tried with your first solution and it worked.